# Adding a TensorFlow Op that uses malloc() and has state

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I wrote a TensorFlow Op that wraps a library written in C that calls `malloc()` internally to allocate buffers and hold state. I initialize the library in the constructor, which is where the `malloc()` calls take place, and then in `Compute()` I use it with a mutex guard. The destructor makes the appropriate calls to `free()`.

In my model each thread creates a copy of the Op, all in the same graph, and runs it within a shared session. The code very often crashes with pointer-related problems, such as "incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed". The unit tests I wrote for the Op, with a single thread, work fine.

I suspect the graph optimizer may be re-using a single instance of the Op, or something like that. Is there a way to tell it that the Op is stateful and that it should be left as-is? Are there other possible reasons for the crash?

I'm running TensorFlow 1.0.0 and compiling the Op with clang 7.0, under OSX 10.10. I compile the C files first into a shared object, and then compile the C++ files together with the shared object.

Comment: If the easiest solution is to fix the library itself, what should I use instead of malloc/free?

Comment: Have you considered running [AddressSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html), [ThreadSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) and/or [UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) on your code? If not; you should. A run of [Clang Tidy](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) and/or [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net) probably wouldn't hurt either... Enabling all warnings in your compiler also never hurts..

Comment: nobody is saying you should not use malloc/free in a C library. The trick is using them correctly ;-).  In a C++ library however you have better options like destructors and smart pointers.

Comment: Yes, common-subexpression eliminator is going to cause problems. Use `.SetIsStateful` . I'm doing it in my memory ops like [this](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/memory_probe_ops/blob/master/memory_probe_ops.cc#L29)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov This is great, thanks! I knew it had to exist because `py_func()` can be made stateful, but I had no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/extend/adding_an_op) on "Adding a New Op":

> Important: Instances of your OpKernel may be accessed concurrently. Your Compute method must be thread-safe. Guard any access to class members with a mutex. Or better yet, don't share state via class members! Consider using a [ResourceMgr](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_mgr.h) to keep track of op state.

Unfortunately, usage of ResourceMgr is quite sketchy as of the time of writing this answer.